# Dell Latitude E6410/ ubuntu 20.04/ Airplane mode switch on automatically

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, dell, airplane-mode

I am using 20.04 and 16.04 versions (dual boot) in my Dell latitude E6410 . In both Operating systems Airplane mode turning on automatically, no matter how many times I switched it off.

I am using 16.04 for 2 months. airplane mode turned on suddenly when  I started computer. After frustration installed 20.04. wifi worked good for some time and then airplane mode started suddenly . From then it is switching on after restart also. When I am turning it off, It is turning on automatically after few seconds.

Comment: Does the airplane mode turn on after you start the computer? Or, is it that the airplane mode suddenly turns on while you are connected to an WiFi? Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1288749/edit) your question to add more information.

Comment: I am using 16.04 for 2 months. airplane mode turned on when  I started computer suddenly. After frustration installed 20.04. wifi worked good for some time and airplane mode started suddenly again. From then it is switching on after restart also. When I am turning it off, It is turning on automatically after few seconds.